# How much DNA does a species lose after post-polyploidization genome downsizing?

Tags: dna, genomics, genomes, polyploidy

After whole genome duplication, diploidization takes place, right? A lot of changings in gene organization and expression involving genetic and epigenetic mechanisms (translocations, transpositions, deletion and / or insertion of sequences, additive or non-additive gene action, transposon activation, gene repression or activation, subfunctionalization, neofunctionalization and so on) cause the genome to shrink a little bit before the species karyotype stabilizes and establishes. But how much DNA, in average, is gone in such process? I guess I have read somewhere that the elimination of redundant repetitive DNA families, causes polyploidization to result in a DNA increase of about 1.5x and not doubling. Is it true? I really would like to have some references on this information or similar.. I did look for, but I couldn't find